# "Open with Visual Studio" is still showing even after uninstalling

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, windows-10

It's kinda weird.

I uninstalled Visual Studio around 3-4 months ago but still, it shows "Open with Visual Studio" when I right-click in file explorer. And "Open with VS code" is not there. I thought it is a bug and reinstalled VS Code but still no changes.

Nothing happens when I click on "Open with Visual Studo".

I am using Windows 10.

Only VS Code is installed in my device:
[image: Only VS Code is installed in my device.]

But it shows Open with Visual Studio:
[image: But it shows Open with Visual Studio]

Thank you!

Comment: go to the registry and remove this entry

Comment: hey @rioV8 could you please provide more information regarding this.

Comment: search for that string `Open with Visual Studio` in the registry and remove that entry

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In regedit, delte:

- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\AnyCode`
- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\AnyCode`

Answer made easily possible thanks to "[Remove items from context menu](https://www.sebastian-segerer.de/post/remove-items-from-context-menu/)" from sebastian-segerer.de (which quotes other sources, superuser being one of them)

Comment: Thanks! Note that there may be another key in `Directory\shell\Anycode` too